# Why is postfix not sending or receiving mail?

Tags: postfix, dovecot

Just bit the bullet and upgraded to Debian Stretch. Everything was working fine for months, if not years before.

I followed the blog post at https://jschumacher.info/2017/06/upgrading-to-debian-stretch-with-dovecot-postfix-opendkim/ to fix two problems I initially encountered.

After everything was seemingly running I didn't bother to send a test mail.

Now that I did I find out that I can neither send or receive emails.

Connections just timeout without error, the mail log (even with debugging output) does not reveal anything useful.

Sending an email produces the following log lines among lots of other less relevant ones:

```
postfix/smtpd[16428]: connect from unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]
...
postfix/smtpd[16428]: report connect to all milters
postfix/smtpd[16428]: milter_macro_lookup: "i"
postfix/smtpd[16428]: milter_macro_lookup: "j"
postfix/smtpd[16428]: milter_macro_lookup: result "domain.com"
postfix/smtpd[16428]: milter_macro_lookup: "{daemon_name}"
postfix/smtpd[16428]: milter_macro_lookup: result "domain.com"
postfix/smtpd[16428]: milter_macro_lookup: "v"
postfix/smtpd[16428]: milter_macro_lookup: result "Postfix 3.1.8"
postfix/smtpd[16428]: milter_macro_lookup: "{if_name}"
postfix/smtpd[16428]: milter_macro_lookup: "_"
postfix/smtpd[16428]: milter_macro_lookup: result "unknown [2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]"
...
postfix/smtpd[16428]: milter8_conn_event: milter unix:/spamass/spamass.sock: connect unknown/2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64
postfix/smtpd[16428]: event: SMFIC_CONNECT; macros: j=domain.com {daemon_name}=domain.com v=Postfix 3.1.8 _=unknown [2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]
postfix/smtpd[16428]: reply: SMFIR_CONTINUE data 0 bytes
...
postfix/smtpd[16428]: milter8_conn_event: milter local:/opendkim/opendkim.sock: connect unknown/2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64
postfix/smtpd[16428]: event: SMFIC_CONNECT; macros: j=domain.com {daemon_name}=domain.com v=Postfix 3.1.8 _=unknown [2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]
postfix/smtpd[16428]: reply: SMFIR_CONTINUE data 0 bytes
postfix/smtpd[16428]: > unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: 220 domain.com ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
postfix/smtpd[16428]: < unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: EHLO [IPv6:2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]
...
postfix/smtpd[16428]: > unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: 250-domain.com
postfix/smtpd[16428]: > unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: 250-PIPELINING
postfix/smtpd[16428]: > unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: 250-SIZE 52428800
postfix/smtpd[16428]: > unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: 250-VRFY
postfix/smtpd[16428]: > unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: 250-ETRN
postfix/smtpd[16428]: > unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: 250-STARTTLS
postfix/smtpd[16428]: > unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5
postfix/smtpd[16428]: > unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: 250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5
postfix/smtpd[16428]: > unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
postfix/smtpd[16428]: > unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: 250-8BITMIME
postfix/smtpd[16428]: > unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: 250 DSN
postfix/smtpd[16428]: < unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: STARTTLS
...
postfix/smtpd[16428]: > unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
...
postfix/smtpd[16428]: Anonymous TLS connection established from unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
...
postfix/smtpd[16428]: < unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: EHLO [IPv6:2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64
...
postfix/smtpd[16428]: > unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: 250-domain.com
postfix/smtpd[16428]: > unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: 250-PIPELINING
postfix/smtpd[16428]: > unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: 250-SIZE 52428800
postfix/smtpd[16428]: > unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: 250-VRFY
postfix/smtpd[16428]: > unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: 250-ETRN
postfix/smtpd[16428]: > unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5
postfix/smtpd[16428]: > unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: 250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5
postfix/smtpd[16428]: > unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
postfix/smtpd[16428]: > unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: 250-8BITMIME
postfix/smtpd[16428]: > unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: 250 DSN
postfix/smtpd[16428]: < unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: AUTH PLAIN xxxx=
...
postfix/smtpd[16428]: > unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
postfix/smtpd[16428]: < unknown[2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64]: MAIL FROM:<me@domain.com> BODY=8BITMIME SIZE=5184
```

and then that's it. It just stops doing anything and Thunderbird eventually complains the action timed out, but the mail log doesn't notice (no line about a dropped connection or something alike).

If I increase the verbosity even more, the very last thing that actually happens is:

```
postfix/smtpd[30091]: vstream_fflush_some: fd 23 flush 42
```

If I add `-v` to just about everything in `master.cf` the last thing happening is:

```
postfix/trivial-rewrite[18140]: dict_mysql_get_active: attempting to connect to host 127.0.0.1
postfix/trivial-rewrite[18140]: dict_mysql: successful connection to host 127.0.0.1
```

Here is my `postconf -n`:

```
alias_maps = $alias_database
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
compatibility_level = 2
debug_peer_level = 9999
debug_peer_list = [2a02:xxxx:xxxx:9880:b5f0:b045:109d:4b64], otherdomain.net
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
default_destination_concurrency_limit = 20
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
inet_interfaces = all
local_destination_concurrency_limit = 2
local_transport = local
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 52428800
mydestination = localhost
mydomain = domain.com
myhostname = domain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 192.168.0.0/16
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/rbl_override, reject_unauth_destination, reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_hostname
smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = yes
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/rbl_override reject_unauth_destination, reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_non_fqdn_recipient
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sender_login_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender_permissions.cf
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_sender_login_mismatch, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_helo_hostname
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
tls_high_cipherlist = AES128+EECDH:AES128+EDH:AES256-SHA256:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:2000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/kunden/mail/
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = static:2000
```

I don't know what else to try or look at, everything I can see seems fine to me.

My stack is:

- postfix
- dovecot
- spamassassin
- spamass-milter
- opendkim
- mysql (postfix-mysql, dovecot-mysql) (for accounts and aliases)

How do I send and receive emails again?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by restarting the MySQL server:

```
systemctl restart mysql postfix
```